# Ubuntu matlab installed but not working

Tags: 16.04, matlab

In Ubuntu 16.04, Matlab isn't working. Matlab says I can't edit the matlab file:

```
Matlab couldn't write a file. Are you using it as root?
```

I am not running as root as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install and run it to the home folder (for example into `~/Software/matlab`) without root privileges.

Previous versions such as R2008b work normally. For such installation you can create the following desktop-file:

```
cat << EOF > ~/Desktop/matlab.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/$USER/Software/matlab/bin/matlab -desktop
Name=MATLAB
Icon=/home/$USER/Software/matlab/X11/icons/matlab64c_icon.xpm

EOF
```

Comment: Yes, i worked when i installed R2008b and i activated license.