# Opening a package (Matlab) from the home directory (or from a launcher) without navigating to the installation directory & without root permission?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, permissions, launcher, matlab

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.03LTS OS.

I have installed **Matlab** in this directory `...usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a`. The installation completed without any problem. But when I try to open **Matlab** I have to navigate to that directory, specifically to `...usr/local/.../R2015a/bin$`, and use the **root permission** to open it.

My questions are:

1. How can I open this package (Matlab) from the home directory **without having to navigate to that directory** where it is installed and **without a root permission** ?
2. Even better, I would like to know how to create a simple icon in the **launcher** and open Matlab  without having to open it from the terminal ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu matlab installed but not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988489/ubuntu-matlab-installed-but-not-working)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not !!

Comment: How exactly did you install it? it sounds like something went wrong - IIRC there should be a symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/matlab` that points to the startup script (and should "just work" since /usr/local/bin should be in your default `PATH`)

Comment: @steeldriver, when I try to open it using 
`la@la-lenovo:~$ matlab` I got `matlab: command not found`  I have to navigate to the directory and run Matlab like this `la@la-lenovo:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin$ sudo ./matlab`

Comment: @OmarOomar As steeldriver said, can you please describe how you installed MATLAB?

Comment: via iso file. but i have found a solution to my problem. I think I should remove this question. what do you think @steeldriver !!!

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my request.

1. I have installed **matlab-support package** using:

   > sudo apt-get install matlab-support

this will add an entry to the launcher and some other features.

2. After completion, I have  changed the ownership of the `.matlab` folder in the home folder to my own user account because I do not want to run Matlab as a **super user**. I have used the felowing command

   > cd ~ sudo chown username -R ~/.matlab

Now, Matlab is working as was intended.