# how to get a launcher desktop icon for matlab R2019a

Tags: software-installation, .desktop, matlab

i am very new to Linux as a whole. I use an alienware 15 R2 with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on it.

i have installed matlab R2019a in the folder `/media/srikar/Code/Matlab`.

The `./matlab` code path is `/media/srikar/Code/Matlab/bin`.

Please help me create a desktop launcher icon. I have gone through other answers for similar cases, but i couldn't figure out how to solve the issue in my case where the installed directory is different from the default. I installed matlab on my external drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu matlab installed but not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988489/ubuntu-matlab-installed-but-not-working) (check only desktop-file part, change it to suite your needs).

Comment: One reason the other answers might not work in this instance is if files on the external drive are not executable (either because of its filesystem type, or a mount option such as `noexec`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create .desktop file and put it in special folder = *homedir*/.local/share/applications/matlab.desktop.
Desktop file example follows, just change to correct path to your matlab binary.
After that matlab will appear in applications list, you can copy desktop shortcut to desktop or anywhere else.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1
Name=Matlab
Comment=Your comment
Keywords=matlab
Exec=/media/srikar/Code/Matlab/bin/yourbinary
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=true
Type=Application
Icon=preferences-system
Categories=GTK;Development;
StartupNotify=false
```

Comment: hello, thank you very much for the answer. It worked well. The thing is, there was a        - desktop needed in the end of Exec or else matlab just splashed and did not do anything. After i added that, everything is working the way i need it to. again, thanks for the help and taking time. This community is the reason why newbies like me are able to get into linux.